# Why does the caret::train function generate an error if called with a formula instead of x,y?

Tags: r, r-caret

In the following example, the predict function generates an error when the model is produced by the caret::train function called with a formula (y~x).  The predict function works if the model was generated with an x,y specification.  Why is this? Should one use the x,y specification? Until now I thought it was just based on user preference?  Is there a way to make the predict function work with the formula specification?

I had thought the models might be different because of the use of factor variables. However, the models appear to produce identical regression equations.  There is no difference in the in-sample predictions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
data("diamonds")
set.seed(42)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(diamonds$price, p=0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- diamonds[trainIndex,]
test <- diamonds[-trainIndex,]
lm_formula <- train(
    price ~ ., train,
    method = "lm",
    trControl=trainControl(method="none")
)
lm_xy <- train(y = train$price,
                 x = train[,-which(colnames(train)=="price")],
                 method = "lm",
                 trControl=trainControl(method="none")
)

# the following generates the error shown beneath it
pred_formula <- predict(lm_formula$finalModel,test)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cut.L' not found

pred_xy <- predict(lm_xy$finalModel,test)

# The following produces zero indicating the in-sample fits are identical
sum((lm_formula$finalModel$fitted.values-lm_xy$finalModel$fitted.values)^2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the fact you are not using caret predict function but rather `predict.lm` because of the class of

```
class(lm_xy$finalModel) #lm
```

If you just do

```
pred_formula <- predict(lm_formula, test)
pred_xy <- predict(lm_xy, test)
```

using caret `predict.train` which will predict upon the best model:

```
all.equal(pred_xy, pred_formula)
#TRUE
```

now if you check:

```
summary(lm_formula$finalModel)
summary(lm_xy$finalModel)
```

you will see the name of the contrasts in the formula case has `` around several  instances which prevents the default `predict.lm` from functioning correctly. This is not an issue for caret `predict.train`.